# How to add third party script after closing body tag for certain pages only in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS application where a third party script is only needed on certain pages. Currently it is firing on all pages, but this is causing some issues.

It's currently added after the closing `body` tag via a custom `_document.js` file. As the script has to go in the body, I can't use the `head` option in NextJS.

What would be the best way to only have this fire on a specific page template?

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import Script from 'next/script';

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
        <Head></Head>
        <body>
            <Main />
            <NextScript />

            {/** Below script only needed on certain pages */}
            <script
                src="xxx"
                id="widget"
            />
        </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do this in `_app.js` instead:

```js
import Script from 'next/script'

const allowedPages = new Set([...]);

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const { asPath } = useRouter();
  const enableScript = allowedPages.has(asPath);
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      {enableScript && <Script id="widget" src="xxx" />}
    </>
  )
}
```

Because you'll have access to `useRouter` and it will update on every page navigation. `_document.js` is only used on the *first* SSR

Comment: Thanks for that! I have updated `_app.js`, the script seems to be loading on page refresh for the required pages (no longer firing on all pages), but isn't when routing from another page. I made some amends to use `pathname` over `asPath` as I have multiple pages it needs to fire on, so it now checks for `/properties/[uid]`.